# Javascript error Multiple checkbox not working

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, checkbox, dynamic-programming

I am facing issue when I use checkbox dynamically with Javascript and Php.
I have fetched data from my localhost database and used php to show data in a row (for multiple rows),
each row have a checkbox and when i click on the checkbox the data from the checkbox get inserted in input type="text" for my comfort.

The ISSUE is: the first checkbox is working fine and puts the data in the input type="text" as i wanted, but other checkbox are not working according to the javascript code and does not put the data in the text box.

```
<!-- html code-->  
<table>
<tbody>
 <form action="insertattendance.php" method="post">
                      
   <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $total;?>" name="numbers" />
   <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $post['lid'];?>" name="eid[]" />
   <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $post['fname'];?>" name="fname[]" />
   <tr>
   <td><?php echo $post['lid']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $post['fname']; ?></td>
   <td><label>
    <div class="button r" id="button-1">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="attendance" id="attendance" checked />
    <div class="knobs"></div>
    <div class="layer"></div>
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="hidden_attendance[]" id="hidden_attendance" value=" " />
   </label></td>
   </tr>
 </form>
</tbody>
</table>
   
<!--Attendance Selecting script -->
   <script>        
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#attendance').change(function(){
   if($(this).prop('checked'))
      {
      $('#hidden_attendance').val('Absent');
      }
      else
      {
      $('#hidden_attendance').val('Present');
      }
   });
   });
   </script>
```

Note: Php code is working fine for the first checkbox and the value is getting stored in the database else are just blank values.

[image: Image attached for reference]

Comment: Is this a JS problem, or a PHP problem? What have you tried to resolve it? And how is your problem related to [tag:dynamic-programming]?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. .  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.